# In C# How to concatenate values with strings in RDLC IIf condition expression?

Tags: c#, rdlc

when i concatenate value with string  in rdlc if  condition  expression , report can't run.

```
=iif(Fields!GrpID.Value = 8,Fields!GrpName.Value,"Sub Total (" +Fields!GrpName.Value + ")")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
=IIf(Fields!GrpID.Value = 8,Fields!GrpName.Value,"Sub Total (" +Fields!GrpName.Value + ")")
```

If you are getting any specific error please add that your question.